# testing @MockBean with @Qualifier throws NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I have 2 interfaces with a common impl

```
interface ReadService {
    fun getSomething()
}

interface ReadWriteService: ReadService {
    fun doSoemthing()
}

class ReadWriteServiceImpl(..): ReadWriteService {
    override fun getSomething()

    override fun doSoemthing()
}
```

I require 2 instances of ReadWriteServiceImpl, one casted to ReadWriteService and other casted to ReadService (for the puspose of initialising these services with different db host configs. replica host vs master host). So I'm initializing it inside spring boot application as:

```
@Bean
@Qualifier("readWrite")
fun getReadWriteService(readWriteConfig): ReadWriteService {
    return ReadWriteServiceImpl(..)
}

@Bean
@Qualifier("readOnly")
fun getReadService(readOnlyConfig): ReadService {
    return ReadWriteServiceImpl(..)
}

@Bean
fun getController(
    @Autowired @Qualifier("readWrite") readWriteService: ReadWriteService,
    @Autowired @Qualifier("readOnly") readService: ReadService
): Controller {
    return Controller(
        readService = readService,
        readWriteService = readWriteService
    )
}
```

Above gets initialized successfully and server seems to be running without any bean conflict. However, when I try to test this using below, I get `NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException, expected single matching bean but found 2`

```
@WebFluxTest(controllers = [Controller::class])
@ContextConfiguration(
    classes = [Controller::class]
)
class ControllerTest(@Autowired val webTestClient: WebTestClient) {

    @MockkBean
    @Qualifier("readWrite")
    private lateinit var readWriteService: ReadWriteService

    @MockkBean
    @Qualifier("readOnly")
    private lateinit var readService: ReadService
}
```

I have also tried using `@Autowired` for injecting custom created beans (with mocked services inside) using `@WebAppConfiguration` but I get the same `NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException`. Can anyone help me fixing this issue if I'm doing anyhting wrong? or this is a bug with the `@WebFluxTest` itself?

Comment: found a workaround for now. using `@MockBean(name = "readWriteService")` and `@MockBean(name = "readService")` seems to solve the problem.

Comment: The workaround you provided is actually the solution. `@Qualifier` is used to tell Spring which bean to inject by passing the name of the bean. In your test you're using `@MockBean` to create the bean, so you have to use `@MockBean(name = "..")` to configure the name of the bean so that the `@Qualifier` annotation works.